# How to search through strings in Pyspark column and selectively replace some strings (containing specific substrings) with a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, string, pyspark

I have a column in a Spark Dataframe that contains a list of strings. I am hoping to do the following and am not sure how:

1. Search the column for the presence of a substring, if this substring is present, replace that string with a word.
2. If one of the desired substrings is not present, then replace the string with 'other'

Sample SDF:

```
data = [
    [1, ["EQUCAB", "EQUCAS", "CANMA"]],
    [2, ["CANMA", "FELCAT", "SUSDO"]],
    [3, ["BOSTAU", "EQUCAB"]],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Item", "String"])
df["String"] = [",".join(map(str, l)) for l in df["String"]]

sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Desired output:

```
data = [
    [1, ["horse", "horse", "other"]],
    [2, ["other", "cat", "other"]],
    [3, ["cow", "horse"]],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Item", "String"])
df["String"] = [",".join(map(str, l)) for l in df["String"]]
```

so basically, any element that contains `EQU` is assigned `horse`, any element that contains `FEL` is assigned `cat`, any element that contains `BOS` is assigned `cow`, and the rest are assigned other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lit

df = df.withColum("String",
                    when(col('String').contains('EQU'), lit('horse'))
                    .when(col('String').contains('FEL'), lit('cat'))
                    .when(col('String').contains('BOS'), lit('cow')).otherwise(lit('other')))
```